# ¿Cómo podría traducir startup?

Tags: traducción, género

Buenas chicos y chicas de spanish.stackexchange, estoy escribiendo un documento académico sobre un trabajo de investigación, tengo que escribir sobre `startup`s en un punto y no estoy seguro de cómo debería usar la palabra, traduzco la misma como "Nuevo emprendimiento" pero no me convence, y como no está en la RAE como anglicismo, no estoy seguro de qué deba hacer. 
Además si fuera a usarla, ¿con qué género debería concordar? ¿`La` startup? ¿`El` startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si quieres usar el anglicismo es **una** startup (femenino).

Si quieres usar un término en español usa "[Empresa emergente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empresa_emergente)", o algunos de los otros aportados en la web enlazada:

- empresa emergente
- compañía emergente
- sociedad emergente
- compañía de arranque
- compañía incipiente

> Una **empresa emergente, compañía emergente, compañía de arranque, compañía incipiente** (conocido en Hispanoamérica como: **compañía startup**) es un término utilizado actualmente en el mundo empresarial el cual busca arrancar, emprender o montar un nuevo negocio y hace referencia a ideas de negocios que están empezando o están en construcción, es decir, son empresas emergentes apoyadas en la tecnología.

Por esa razón se usa el femenino con *startup*: nos referimos a una empresa o compañía (ambos nombres femeninos) y *startup* viene a ser un calificativo que se convierte en nombre.

> Juan ha encontrado trabajo en un**a** (compañí**a**/empres**a**) *startup*

Comment: http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/una-start-up-es-una-empresa-emergente-835/ tiene *emergente* (es posible decir *sociedad* en vez de *empresa/compañía*, también femenina). Una vez mencionadas en un contexto, es fácil referir a ellas simplemente como *las emergentes*, imagino.

Comment: @guifa, lo añado, dejando en enlace en los comentarios. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No me gusta ninguno de esos términos. Prefiero *nuevos emprendimientos/empresas nuevas.*

Comment: En Chile se dice _emprendimientos_ (como aporta @Gustavson, pero a secas, sin "nuevos").

Comment: Todas las empresas nuevas serían entonces startups ? Suena muy general

Answer (score 2):

Empresa emergente.

Según la [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/una-start-up-es-una-empresa-emergente-835/#:%7E:text=En%20el%20mundo%20de%20los,impulsada%20por%20otros%20inversores%20o):

> En el mundo de los negocios, y muy especialmente en el ámbito de la
> innovación y las nuevas tecnologías, se denomina empresa start-up a
> aquella sociedad que, pese a su juventud y falta de recursos, consigue
> obtener resultados en el mercado y pasar a un siguiente nivel
> estructural al ser impulsada por otros inversores o absorbida por
> empresas ya consolidadas.

Sí, puedes elegir decir **una startup**, pero dado que quieres la traducción... deberías usar **empresa emergente**, ya que sí existe el término acuñado en español.

Y no, la "nueva ferretería en mi barrio" no es una empresa "startup". Ese ejemplo es incorrecto. Es un negocio, sí, pero no una empresa.

> De forma muy breve y para que se te quede grabado, un negocio es un
> sistema que está creado para la generación de beneficios, mientras que
> una empresa es ese sistema llevado a la creación de una organización
> que obtiene un lucro.

[https://lawks.co/blog/que-diferencias-hay-entre-un-negocio-una-empresa-y-proyecto-de-empresa/#:~:text=%C2%BFQu%C3%A9%20diferencia%20hay%20entre%20un,organizaci%C3%B3n%20que%20obtiene%20un%20lucro](https://lawks.co/blog/que-diferencias-hay-entre-un-negocio-una-empresa-y-proyecto-de-empresa/#:%7E:text=%C2%BFQu%C3%A9%20diferencia%20hay%20entre%20un,organizaci%C3%B3n%20que%20obtiene%20un%20lucro).

Answer (score 1):

**Una startup.** Los que trabajamos en startups no las llamamos de otra manera.

Y claro que habrá dudas sobre lo que esto significa. ¿Es acaso tan general? La nueva ferretería de mi barrio es una "empresa emergente", pero no es una startup.

Es un anglicismo, pero en inglés es también un concepto relativamente nuevo y fluctuante. Hay sin embargo características específicas que separan a una startup de otras empresas emergentes, incipientes, etc. Por ejemplo, plantean un modelo de negocio **repetible y escalable**. El consenso es también que una startup es una empresa diseñada para **crecer a un ritmo acelerado**.

[What is a startup? - Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/natalierobehmed/2013/12/16/what-is-a-startup/) (en inglés)